# setting error states during Linux RPM install/upgrade

Tags: linux, installation, rpm

I'm currently developing my first Linux RPM package for release.  During the %post hook, I want to ensure that a particular file is resident on the target system.  If this file is present, I'd like the install to proceed.  If this file is missing, I'd like RPM to abort the install and report an error code.

Conditional logic in the .spec file works fine, but adding "return 1" in the error case causes RPM to throw an error (and, ironically, RPM does return with an error code in that case).  But what is the "right" way to tell RPM that an install has failed and to exit gracefully?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That particular file is part of the RPM? If not, the correct place to do this check is in the %pre section. If it is, you can use the %verify for verification. When the %post run, the package is installed already, so it cannot be "failed"

Answer (score 1):

Either put the check in the `%pre` section, or add it to the `Requires` field to make `rpm` itself check for you.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the "right" way to tell RPM that an install has failed and to
>   exit gracefully?

Best practice would say that the RPM installation should not fail if all the listed dependencies are met.

It does sound very much like the file is a dependency, in which case it should be listed as **Requires:**/path/to/file.

If it's a site-specific file for which you control deployment, then the RPM should deploy its own good default, which you can specify under **%files** with *%config(noreplace)*. This will ensure that any existing config is not overwritten, and the default is written as */path/to/file.rpmnew*.

If you want to replace an existing config, you would use *%config* without the *(noreplace)* option, which causes the existing file to be moved aside to */path/to/file.rpmsave*